# Why does ComboBox not initially show the ComboBoxItem with IsSelected==true?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

In the following code, why doesn't the item with property `IsSelected` set to `true` become selected in the `ComboBox` just as it does in the `ListBox` after clicking the `Button`?
[image]

Once I click on the `ComboBox`, the selected item becomes selected, but not before.
[image]

**xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Desktop.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Txt}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Txt}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Select second item" Click="Button_Click"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.Desktop
{
    [Export]
    public partial class Shell : Window
    {
        public class Foo : NotificationObject
        {
            static int _seq = 0;
            string _txt = "Item " + (++_seq).ToString();
            public string Txt { get { return _txt; } }
            bool _isSelected;
            public bool IsSelected
            {
                get { return _isSelected; }
                set
                {
                    _isSelected = value; 
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Foo> Items { get; set; }

        public Shell()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Items.Add(new Foo());
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items[1].IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the ItemContainerStyle is applied only when the ComboBoxItems are generated (i.e. when you open the dropdown).

To work around this, you create another property called SelectedItem and bind the Combobox's SelectedValue to it.

[Long explanation and example here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30a45233-dc01-40ca-9ead-fa816c395697)

Answer (score 1):

Because the binding is set on `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` by default, you would have to change it to `PropertyChanged` to get the result you want.
Like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="IsSelected"Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: In your code you change the binding for a ListBoxItem but the issue is with ComboBoxItem; I tried changing the binding for ComboBoxItem, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Model as the `DataContext` for a WPF Window, the Controls may not initially behave as you'd expect. Essentially, some properties/events never get set/called until after the Window been initialized. The work-around in this case is to setup the binding in the Window's `Loaded` event.

*Disclaimer*: I have not tested this with the OP's specific scenario, but this is the behavior and work-around I've encountered in the past.